# Why can I use both v <- 2:8 AND v <- c(2:8) in R?

Tags: r

From tutorialspoint.com's R section:
    The colon operator creates the series of numbers in sequence for a vector.

`2:8` in console gives me

`[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

`c(2:8)` gives me the same thing

`[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

It says to create a vector with more than one element, you must use the c() function. So

`c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` would be the equivalent of c(2:8), I'd think.

Yet, class of c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8) gives me "numeric", whereas class of c(2:8) gives me "integer".

1. Why are these two different? 2:8 is just a series of numbers between 2 and 8 inclusive...
2. And why is it valid in R to use either `v <- 2:8` OR `v <- c(2:8)` (they're the same).

I'm looking for an explanation into why this works, or an intuitive way to think about it, or how the r interpreter handles the colon operator. Using class() to try and figure out what's going on has only increased my confusion :(

Comment: apparently, c(2:8) is the equivalent of c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L) rather than just c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8). I won't ask why, I'll just assume this is a fact I need to remember. The other question is still up for grabs.

Comment: Not exactly, if you head `help(":")` carefully, you'll see that `:` simply returns integers by default. Wrapping it in `c()` doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think of this almost like `2:8` really is like R breaking 2 through 8 and "combining" it using `c()` like `c(2L, 3L, 4L...)`. If we think of it this way, `2:8 == c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L)`. If we were to then try to wrap that in `c()` again, we wouldn't be "combining" it with anything else, so nothing really happens.

`c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L)` is the same as `c(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L))` because `c()` is used for "combining" e.g. `c(2:8, NA)`

It would be like:

```
x <- 4
x <- 4 + 0
x <- 4 + 0 + 0
```

The fact is that all of those are the same, because we're not really changing them by adding 0. The `+` is meant to actually add something.

Same with:

```
x <- 2:8
x <- c(2:8)
x <- c(c(2:8))
```

I hope that helped?

Comment: so the colon operator is already using c() to combine things, and wrapping it in an additional c() is doing nothing because it's the same as combining it with nothing, aka +0